# Existe alguma maneira de chamar uma ação quando o método não existe em um objeto em javascript?

Tags: javascript

No PHP, temos alguns métodos especiais que podem ser incluídos em uma classe.

Um deles é o `__call`, que faz com que uma ação seja invocada (através dele) quando um método não exista numa classe.

Exemplo:

```
class Exemplo
{
    public function existe()
    {
        echo 'Eu existo';
    }

   public function __call($method, $parameters)
   {
       echo "$method não existe, mas vou fazer alguma coisa legal";
   }
}

$e = new Exemplo;

$e->existo(); // 'Eu existo'

$e->nao_existo(); // "nao_existo não existe, mas vou fazer alguma coisa legal"
```

No javascript existe alguma forma de se fazer isso?

Exemplo:

```
function special(){}

special.prototype.existe = function () {
     console.log('Esse método existe');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Não há uma implementação que seja amplamente suportada equivalente à função _call do PHP em JavaScript.**

No ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), existe uma nova implementação que vai permitir algo como o __call, o [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Porém, nem todos os browsers já implementaram esse objeto. No momento, apenas Firefox e Edge dão suporte ao Proxy.

Conforme o exemplo da Mozilla, ele é utilizado dessa forma:

```
var handler = {
    get: function(target, name){
        return name in target?
            target[name] :
            37;
    }
};

var p = new Proxy({}, handler);
p.a = 1;
p.b = undefined;

console.log(p.a, p.b); // 1, undefined
console.log('c' in p, p.c); // false, 37
```

O Firefox dava suporte a uma função fora do padrão que permitia isso. Porém, desde a versão 39, ela não é mais suportada. Veja em [Object.prototype.__noSuchMethod__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod)

```
var obj = {};
obj .__noSuchMethod__ = function (name, args) {
    alert(name);
    alert(args);
}

obj.teste("teste1");
```

Comment: Engraçado: Por que o Firefox sempre tem uma coisa que os outros não tem. Outro exemplo é o `toSource`

Comment: A Mozilla participa ativamente do desenvolvido das novas tecnologias da web, eles geralmente implementam funcionalidades muito novas das especificações mais recentes.

Answer (score 2):

Invocação de funções em *Tipos* que não são funções gera erro em JavaScript.

Ou seja usar `()` no final de uma variável ou propriedade que não seja uma função dá erro e não há uma ferramenta como pelos vistos o PHP tem.

Como contornar isso?

Bom, isso terá de ser feito no código, prevenindo erros.

Pode verificar-se se a variável ou propriedade é uma função:

```
function foo(){
    // fazer algo
}

if (typeof foo === "function") foo();
```

Usar um método para correr funções. No fundo existe já o `.call` ou `.apply`, mas podes criar um próprio também:

```
function corredor(fn, argumentos, fallback) {
    var func = typeof fn === "function" ? fn : fallback;
    return func.apply(this, argumentos);
}

var foo = 'string';
var retorno = corredor(foo, [1, 2, 3], function () {
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
});
console.log(retorno);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txovxymd/